# VSCode doesn't support DOMRectList iteration typings

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

In Javascript I'm able to iterate through a "collection" of `DOMRect` objects (that's what `getClientRects` returns according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects)) but when I switched to typescript VSCode is giving type errors "Type 'DOMRectList' is not an array type or a string type":

[image: image of vscode type error]

Comment: please paste your code as text rather than picture

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQEqugClQGwC5EBRfVAW1TCgEpiA3OGAE0QG8AoRHxCBAM5REAJ2xQAMjCGIAvIgIA6NFADC+GNUziBOWgG5O3XsDgjEOcsLHREcYKPFShtDsd69+YAXHKL8cMg4AETkwFDBADSO0P6o4dHBIjDIABYR0TZQislpdO6IAL6chUA). What version of Typescript are you using? What does your `tsconfig.json` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible with a `target` of `ES5` or lower.

When setting [`--downlevelIteration`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#downlevelIteration) (not recommended), you get a more detailed error message which might help explain things a little

> Type 'DOMRectList' is not an array type or a string type or does not have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

The quick solution is to target `ES2015` or later in your `tsconfig.json` file

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015"
  }
}
```

---

If you do need ES5 support, you'll need to alter your code

```js
for (let i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
  let rect = rects[i]
  // and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil It worked by adding "es2015" as compilerOptions.target and adding "DOM" and "DOM.Iterable" to compilerOptions.lib